# Need of parentheses in sqlite query clause

Tags: sqlite

I am running the following sqlite3 queries and notice that the first two queries are not giving me the expected answer, i.e. 1240969 + 1225691 != 1531026. If I use parentheses around the 'or' clauses I get the expected result. Why is this?

```
sqlite> select count(*) from d where county = "A" or county = "D" and year = "1911";
1240969
sqlite> select count(*) from d where county = "A" or county = "D" and year = "1901";
1225691
sqlite> select count(*) from d where county = "A" or county = "D";
1531026
sqlite> select count(*) from d where (county = "A" or county = "D") and year = "1901";
748015
sqlite> select count(*) from d where (county = "A" or county = "D") and year = "1911";
783011
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between the 2 operators `AND` and `OR`, `AND` has precedence, so  this:

```
county = "A" or county = "D" and year = "1911"
```

evaluates like

```
county = "A" or (county = "D" and year = "1911")
```

so it is not the same to:

```
(county = "A" or county = "D") and year = "1911"
```